# Could a beach have green or blue sand due to a nearby copper deposit? How poisonous would such a beach be?

Tags: color, toxicity, oxides

I am in the midst of a world building project and am wondering about green sand from copper oxide/patina material. The material could either be washed into the water from a nearby land deposit or be coming from an exposed deposit on the lakebed or seafloor. Would it be possible to have vibrant blue or green, or would the particles break down onto something of more boring color? How poisonous would such a beach be with a high copper concentration? How would the salinity of the water affect the situation?
Any answers would be much appreciated. I haven't been able to find any real-world examples of this happening.

Comment: Green sand would be harmless breakdown products of mafic/ultramafic rocks, such as those found in volcanically-active areas. [These beaches in Hawaii are green](https://www.lovebigisland.com/quick-and-remarkable-facts-about-hawaii/green-sand-beach/), read on about the details. Forget about copper.

Comment: Had you asked if it was possible for a beach to be entirely covered with deep red garnets (not gem quality), I could have verified that it was possible: [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5143/79678) is a photo I just took of some of the garnets I scooped up when I visited that beach about 30 years ago. The whole beach looked like that, with very little sand. So maybe a **peridot** beach would suit your world building project!

Comment: I have heard that some soils in the former Belgian Congo are blue /green in some areas. Some copper deposits are exceptionally rich with a few per-cent copper.

Comment: BTW, podzol soils may be initially a blue-green, and change to yellow-brown after exposure to air for some minutes. This is not due to *copper*, but ferrous iron oxidizing to ferric. It's an interesting effect noted on digging into soils in pine forests and taiga (krummholz).

Comment: About blue sands: It contains [Ilmenite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ilmenite#:~:text=Ilmenite%20is%20a%20titanium%2Diron,%2C%20sunscreen%2C%20food%20and%20cosmetics.), which is dark blue in color.  Some part of Sri Lankan beach contain ilmenite and is a export item for the country.